# How to slide jquery slider taking values from database such as ID for slide and NAME for display

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jquery slider and values coming static such as 1 for Nikunj ,2 for Ravi and Upto 5.
But I want 1,2,3,...Or any integer should come from my table ID and also Names come from database table related to my ID.So, How can do this.

I have simple jquery code that is static to 1 to 5, B`enter code here`ut I want any integer that comes from database.
I am using snap to increments slider

My Code In javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`$(function () {enter code here
            $("#slider1").slider({
                value:1,       // this value should come from database
                min: 1,        //this value should come from database
                max: 5,        //this value should come from database
                step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var slideyvalue = getConnectedValueById(ui.value);
                    $("#txtlusty").text(slideyvalue );
                }
            });

        }); 

</script>
```

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - why did you remove the C# tag when the OP indicated he was using C# to retrieve the database values?

Comment: I opened the question only because of C# tag, but it has nothing to do with C#. It should have been tagged as ASP.Net though, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Send them down in a hidden field and reference them via jQuery.

If you're using `MVC` you could do:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model.SliderValue);
@Html.HiddenFor(Model.SliderMinVal);
@Html.HiddeFor(Model.SliderMaxVal);
```

If you're using `ASP.NET WebForms` you could do:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="SliderValue" runat="server" Value='1' />
<asp:HiddenField ID="SliderMinValue" runat="server" Value='50' />
<asp:HiddenField ID="SliderMaxValue" runat="server" Value='100' />
```

Then to pass it to the slider:

```
<script>
      var val = $("#SliderValue").val();
      var minVal = $("#SliderMinVal").val();
      var maxVal = $("#SliderMaxVal").val();

      $("#slider1").slider({
            value:val,       // this value should come from database
            min: minVal,        //this value should come from database
            max: maxVal,        //this value should come from database
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var slideyvalue = getConnectedValueById(ui.value);
                $("#txtlusty").text(slideyvalue );
            }
        });

    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  Is ASP.NET unable to just dynamically generate the javascript function with the values from the database?

Comment: @mbeckish - I think my solution is a little cleaner than dynamically generating javascript in the code behind or directly in an `aspx` page